# SQL how to display group by results in columns postgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I used a** group by **id and year in a SQL query to display the following table :

[image: table query sql]

QueySQL

```
select s.id as societe, typecombustible,extract(YEAR from p.datedebut) as yearrr  
,sum(quantiteconsommee) as somme 
from sch_consomind.consommationcombustible, sch_referentiel.societe s,  sch_referentiel.unite u,sch_referentiel.periode p
where unite=u.id and s.id=u.societe_id and p.id=periode
group by s.id, typecombustible, yearrr
order by yearrr
```

But, I want to display the result by columns, like the following table

[image: resulta wanted]

Searching in google and StackOverflow I found `PIVOT` function which is available in SQL Server, but I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtered aggregation:

```
select s.id as societe, 
       c.typecombustible,
       sum(c.quantiteconsommee) filter (where extract(YEAR from p.datedebut) = 2020) as "2020",
       sum(c.quantiteconsommee) filter (where extract(YEAR from p.datedebut) = 2021) as "2021",
       sum(c.quantiteconsommee) filter (where extract(YEAR from p.datedebut) = 2022) as "2022"
from sch_consomind.consommationcombustible c
  join sch_referentiel.societe s on c.unite = u.id
  join sch_referentiel.unite u on s.id = u.societe_id
  join sch_referentiel.periode p on p.id = c.periode
group by s.id, c.typecombustible
order by s.id, c.typecombustible;
```

---

And before you ask: no, this can not be made "dynamic". A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be known before the database starts retrieving the data.